# How to remove the header from the first page only, with fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, document-classes

Here's a small document that uses the **fancyhdr package** to customize the header.  The output is very nice, for what I need to do.  However, I need the header to appears on all pages except the first page (which has a title).  How can I do that in a minimal way, from the code below?

Take note that I need to keep the footer with its page number on all pages, even on the first page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering\normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead[L]{} %
\fancyhead[C]{\textsc{Some title in the header}}
\fancyhead[R]{} %
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{Page \thepage~of \totalpages}
\fancyfoot[RO]{Page \thepage~of \totalpages}

\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}

\title{\normalfont\normalsize
    \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
    \huge \textsc{Testament} \\
    \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
}

\author{John Doe}
\date{\normalsize\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Some funny title}

\lipsum[2-12]

\end{document}
```

Preview, with the offending header shown in red:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `\thispagestyle{empty}` after  `\maketitle`.

**Edit:**
According to your comment,  you need to (re)define page style  `\plain` (so far you not define it as `fancyhdr` style) and define new page style, let be named `firstpage`. Changed code are indicated by comments in MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering\normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
% new definition of the fancy headers and footers
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\fancypagestyle{plain}% <--- new
{%
\fancyhf{}%             <--- new
\fancyhead[C]{\textsc{Some title in the header}}%
\fancyfoot[LE]{Page \thepage~of \totalpages}%
\fancyfoot[RO]{Page \thepage~of \totalpages}%
}
\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}[plain]% <--- new
{%
\fancyfoot[L,C,R]{}%               <--- new
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\pagestyle{plain}

\title{\normalfont\normalsize
    \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
    \huge \textsc{Testament} \\
    \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
}

\author{John Doe}
\date{\normalsize\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}% <--- new

\section{Some funny title}
\lipsum[2-12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my God!  Why didn’t have found this by myself!  Thanks!!

Comment: @Cham, don't worry (almost) all member here have been (at least) once in similar situation ;-). Happy TeXing!

Comment: Well, your solution removes the page number at the bottom. I need to keep the footer.

Comment: @cham, sorry, I overlooked this, e.g. read only title of your question. Than you need to define new `pagestyle` which has header and empty footer. I will ad this ASAP.

Comment: @Cham, I find some spare time and correct MWE in answer that it should now fulfil your requirement as you explain me in above comment.

Comment: @Zarko: Do you mean `\fancyhead[L,C,R]{}`? This would remove the header for pages using style `firstpage` while `\fancyfoot[L,C,R]{}` removes the footer. Additionally `scrartcl` provides macro `\titlepagestyle` for documents using option `titlepage=false` (default). So it is also possible to use `\renewcommand{\titlepagestyle}{firstpage}` in the preamble to set the page style of the first page.

Comment: @esdd, thank you for comment. I'm not very familiar with `scrartcl˙ package, so I just follow to OP use of `fancyhdr` package. Used code I took from its documentation, of course your suggestion also work.

Comment: @Zarko is there a reason why setting `\fancypagestyle{myStyle}{\lhead{} rhead{}}` after the `\begin{Document}` cause texlive 2020 to timeout? This doesn't happen to text live 2021.

Comment: @Amir, sorry where you see, that I put definition for `mystyle` after `\begin{Document}`? If you have problems with use of `fancyhdr` package, please ask new question, where please provide MWE which demonstrate your problem. I have problems with understanding your comment ...

Answer (score 4):

Off topic, but importent: Do not use package `sectsty` together with a KOMA-Script class. They are incompatible. Replace

```latex
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering\normalfont\scshape}
```

by

```latex
\renewcommand{\raggedsection}{\centering}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\normalfont\scshape}
```

Do not abuse `\date` to change the font size of the date. Replace it by

`\setkomafont{date}{\normalsize}`

To remove the warning regarding `fancyhdr` you could use package `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{Some title in the header}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\renewcommand{\pagemark}{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{Page \thepage~of \totalpages}}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalcolor\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\scshape}

\renewcommand{\raggedsection}{\centering}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\normalfont\scshape}

\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}

\title{\normalfont\normalsize
    \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
    \huge \textsc{Testament} \\
    \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
}

\author{John Doe}
\addtokomafont{date}{\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Some funny title}
\lipsum[2-12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! +1!

Comment: How can we add a rule to the footers (like the rule for the header), but no rule at the bottom of the first page?

Comment: Aah!  For the question in the previous comment, we just have to add the option **footsepline**, to the scrlayer-scrpage package. Works like a charm!

Comment: Yes, if you add `footsepline` to the `scrlayer-scrpage` options, the rule above the footer is inserted for pages using style `scrheadings`. If you would need the rule on `plain` pages (the page with the title header uses `plain` by default) too, you would have to add option `plainfootsepline`.